# Translate theme texts in WordPress site not contained in .po file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, gettext

I'm trying to add another language to a Wordpress site. Some of the translation is being handled by a plugin called Polylang, but I'm also using .po/.mo files to handle some of the text that Polylang can't access.

However, there is some text that isn't showing up even in the .po file that was supplied with the theme.

Here's an example.

There's a setting in the Theme Options to set the text associated with some links (title and description). The php in the theme template is this:

```
<div id="homeheadlinks" class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_firstlink']?>" class="headbutton bone"><i class="golink"></i><?php echo $options['unf_firstlinktitle']?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_firstlinkdesc']?></em></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_secondlink']?>" class="headbutton btwo"><i class="golink"></i><?php echo $options['unf_secondlinktitle']?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_secondlinkdesc']?></em></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_thirdlink']?>" class="headbutton bthree"><i class="golink"></i><?php echo $options['unf_thirdlinktitle']?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_thirdlinkdesc']?></em></a>
    </div>
```

The text can be changed via the theme's options, but there is no way to add a language other than the main one that way.

How could I add translations for the items like `$options['unf_firstlinktitle']` and `$options['unf_firstlinkdesc']`.

Just to be clear, these items don't show up in Polylang's String Translations section.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. I'll give you feedback once I've tried it. I do thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what I did and it seemed to work. I decided to add something similar to what LoicTheAztec suggested.

In each one of those links, I changed them to

```
<a href="<?php pll_e('http://mydomainname.com/englishpage/', 'mytheme-child') ?>" class="headbutton bone"><i class="golink"></i><?php pll_e('Link text', 'mytheme-child') ?> <em><?php pll_e ('Link description', 'mytheme-child') ?></em></a>https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang-theme-strings/
```

Then I installed the plugin [Polylang Theme Strings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang-theme-strings/), which put all of the new strings I created with `pll_e()` into Polylang's String Translation tabs. From there I did the translations (after choosing Show All Languages in the menu bar at the top.)

It works *almost* perfectly. I have one other issue, which I'll post about if I can't resolve it myself soon.

Answer (score 3):

As your code  is associated to some settings in your theme, you could override them directly with a [gettex native translatable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) in your php theme templat. You will need replacing **`'the title …'`** by your real titles and **`'your_theme_slug'`** by your real theme slug) in the code below:

```
    <div id="homeheadlinks" class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_firstlink']?>" class="headbutton bone"><i class="golink"></i><?php _e('the title …', 'your_theme_slug'); ?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_firstlinkdesc']?></em></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_secondlink']?>" class="headbutton btwo"><i class="golink"></i><?php _e('the title …', 'your_theme_slug'); ?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_secondlinkdesc']?></em></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $options['unf_thirdlink']?>" class="headbutton bthree"><i class="golink"></i><?php _e('the title …', 'your_theme_slug'); ?> <em><?php echo $options['unf_thirdlinkdesc']?></em></a>
    </div>
```

Then you will need to rescan this template with Polylang for new strings, and you will find out 3 new translatable strings. This is the fastest way to solve your issue. But, if not done yet, It will be much better to enable a child theme, copying this changed file into it, avoiding this way loosing changes when theme get updated…

Reference: [I18n for WordPress Developers (gettex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)